# How to avoid null values in a FOR loop to handle list objects in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lapply

I want to produce summary statistics using a `for` loop in a batch.

```
#--Zone statistics
zone <- lapply(YieldPts, function(a){extract(NewDatasetRaster[[11]], a)}) 
# extract zone variable by points

summary(YieldPts)
 Length Class                  Mode
[1,] 8489   SpatialPointsDataFrame S4  
[2,] 6300   SpatialPointsDataFrame S4  
[3,] 7484   SpatialPointsDataFrame S4  
[4,] 8583   SpatialPointsDataFrame S4  
[5,] 6761   SpatialPointsDataFrame S4  
[6,] 7244   SpatialPointsDataFrame S4 

summary(zone)
     Length Class  Mode   
[1,] 8489   -none- numeric
[2,] 6300   -none- numeric
[3,] 7484   -none- numeric
[4,] 8583   -none- numeric
[5,] 6761   -none- numeric
[6,] 7244   -none- numeric
```

`YieldPts` is a large list that contains spatial points data frame.

`NewDatasetRaster` is a raster stack.

I use `lapply` to extract data from a raster layer, which works fine.

But when I create an empty list called `zone_stat`, then use a `for` loop to produce summary statistics for each list, it outputs null values for the first five lists, which confuses me:

```
zone_stat <- list()
for (i in length(YieldPts)) {
zone_stat[[i]] <- aggregate(YieldPts[[i]]$yield, 
                             by=list(zone[[i]]), 
                             FUN=summary)
} 

summary(zone_stat)
     Length Class      Mode
[1,] 0      -none-     NULL
[2,] 0      -none-     NULL
[3,] 0      -none-     NULL
[4,] 0      -none-     NULL
[5,] 0      -none-     NULL
[6,] 2      data.frame list
```

Then I actually checked each list individually and it worked fine:

```
zone_stat[[1]] <- aggregate(YieldPts[[1]]$yield, 
                         by=list(zone[[1]]), 
                         FUN=summary)
```

Please tell me what I do wrong so I can avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop executes only one time. `for (i in length(YieldPts))` is running a for a single value, the length of `YieldPts`.

Use `for (i in 1:length(YieldPts))` or `for (i in seq_along(YieldPts))`. The latter is preferred and considered a good practice (consider the case where the object has length zero to see why).